# Returns after a condition was met in Pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I want to test how the returns of SPX has been in the next 12 month after a condition has been met. I don't know how to put that into Pinescript. Can somebody help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to learn pinescript basics concepts then
https://www.pinecoders.com/learning_pine_roadmap/

Takes a bit of time but once you'll go through it completely, you'll be able to figure the answer out
Your question is too broad and not specific enough to allow us to help you

Dave